# Get information from link tag with javascript and analyze it

Tags: javascript, html, excel, rss

I'm not really proficient in Javascript or in HTML and I have to use it to get information from an RSS flux. The RSS flux can be [found here](https://www.cfnews.net/rss/feed/m_a_corporate).

I need to get the company names found in each article. I have noticed that they're often at the 5th or 6th place in the `<link>` tags as shown below:
[image]

and I've managed to get the link tags from the whole document by doing the following:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("link")).forEach(function (ele) { 
   console.log(ele);
});
```

The picture below shows the result:
[image]

The problem is that whenever I try to do something with it (apply a regexp with `/^https*$/.exec(ele)` for example) it does not work.
Does anybody know how I could access this information?
Also after that, I'll need to put the different company names into an excel sheet so if anyone has a better solution that can be directly written to an excel sheet I'll take it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this and then execute a regex instead of the `console.log`

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("link")).forEach(function (ele){ console.log(ele.value;})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :DD. But the console gives me `null` as a result because the <link> tag does not have attributes and I want to get the information in between the tags. Here is how it looks like : <link>https://etc.com</link>. I'm not sure if I can get the information in between?

Comment: Try to change .getAttributes to .element